# Create a context free grammar for the sub-lang of java prototypes

Tags: java, context-free-grammar

I am new to context free grammar and i've only learned stuff like left/rightmost derivation and G=(V, E, R ,S) so far. But the problem I'm trying to solve involves java prototype and I'm not very good at java. So I don't really know where to start.

Give a context-free grammar for the sub-language of Java prototypes.

```
int myMethod();
double myMethod(int x, double y);
static double f(int x, double y, int z);
public static double g();
```

These are methods and variables, how can I relate to things like S => Sa | e ? And what is the start symbol?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All java you need to know about method signatures is located on single [doc page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html). You start writing grammar by identifying grammar variables. The obvious ones to start with are

```
- type
- argument_name
- method_name
- parenthesis (2 terminal symbols)
- comma (terminal)
- semicolon (terminal)
```

You introduce more variables while writing grammar rules, for example

```
argument_list : argument
              | argument, comma, argument_list
```

As soon as you finish your grammar you'd have the "top most rule":

```
method_signature : ...
```

The `method_signature` is the start symbol.

Comment: Thank you. I will read the specification and see if I can understand.

Comment: Hi Tegiri, could you take a look at the solution I came up with? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Take ready java grammar parser (e.g. from http://www.antlr.org/grammar/list) and throw away all the needless stuff.

Comment: thank you for the resource. but what is the rule for this particular question? is int myMethod() the start symbol?

Comment: Where is the fun of discovery if you are told everything?

Comment: the start symbol is `declaration_list`, the start rule is `declaration_list:(declaration semicolon)*`

Comment: strict declaration definitions can be taken from the specification http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html

Comment: thank you very much! the specification is exactly what i am looking for!

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with. Could you take a minute to see if this makes any sense?

```
S -> AB 
A -> PCT | CT | T 
B -> M(V);
V -> TX | TX,V | e

T -> int | double
C -> static | e
P -> public | e
M -> myMethod | f | g
X -> x | y | z
```

Comment: One letter grammar variables are OK in CS parsing curriculum, but for practical grammars you'd better have more meaningful programer style names. Thus, looking into individual rule would make its correctness obvious (without detective work what obfuscated symbols mean). Also method name (M?) should be made more general -- identifier. Identifiers are recognized on lexical analysis stage.